# How to handle loading and completion without using futurebuilder in flutter

Tags: flutter, async-await, future

I cannot distinguish two different situations by the method in the example. How can I handle loading and completion situations?

```
//async method   

     void list() {
            databaseHelper.list().then((records) {
             setState(() {
              _recordList = records;
             });
            });
          }
```

---

```
_recordList.length > 0
 ? ListView.builder(
     itemCount: _recordList.length,
     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     return {....}                          
   })
   : Center(
       child: Text("No Record"),
     ),
```

I want to show CircularProgressIndicator () until the list is loaded, but if the list is empty, I want to show "No Record".

What is the way to do without using futurebuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can handle it with value null or 0

```
void list() {
  _recordList = null;
            databaseHelper.list().then((records) {
             setState(() {
              _recordList = records;
             });
            });
          }
```

but the void list, must return a new List() when they found no records..

```
_recordList == null ? new new CircularProgressIndicator() : 
_recordList.length > 0
 ? ListView.builder(
     itemCount: _recordList.length,
     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     return {....}                          
   })
   : Center(
       child: Text("No Record"),
     ),
```

Comment: Great! @FloW.
I had tried this, but it hadn't work because I hadn't set null the list. 

`_recordList = null;`